# iPhone. Detect another finger touch during one finger is touching on the screen

Tags: iphone, ipad, touch

Is it possible to detect another finger touch during one finger is touching on the screen? I need to deal with the gesture of the 2nd finger during which I don't want my first finger to leave the screen. What should be the general logic in the code to handle this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Set your view's [`multipleTouchEnabled` property](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW34) to yes. Then in your `-touchesXXX:…`, the first argument (NSSet* *touches*) will contain 2 elements when 2 fingers are touching the screen.

Answer (score 0):

^ yup multiTouchEnabled is correct also if tracking movements try to keep track of each of the 2 touchBegin  positions and when a touchMove is received their correspondents will most likely correspond to the finger with the closest previous touch position.